# How to expand macro in a macro call

Tags: macros, itemize, expansion

How can I expand a macro inside an optional argument list

```
\newcommand{\sss}{%
label={$\bullet$},topsep=0mm, parsep=0mm,% leftmargin=3mm,rightmargin=0cm,labelwidth=5mm,labelsep=3mm%
}

\begin{itemize}[\sss] 
\item gugus
\end{itemize}
```

This does not work, (not giving any good debuggin message).
So the expansion is wrong?

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is the typical `trap` with key-value-interfaces, it won't work this way

Comment: What is the trap here :-) or better what does latex do when inserting the macro?

Comment: The trap is the non-expansion of key-value - parsers, but David Carlisle stated this already

Comment: There are some solutions to this question as well other answers to your other questions, but you rarely accept answers -- that's not really a proof of approving the efforts by users in order to help you

Answer (score 3):

keyval parsers typically don't expand the arguments (otherwise things like `font=\small` would blow up badly as `\small` would expand too early.

so the simplest thing is to use

```
\newenvironment{sss}{%
\begin{itemize}[label={$\bullet$},topsep=0mm, parsep=0mm,% leftmargin=3mm,rightmargin=0cm,labelwidth=5mm,labelsep=3mm%
]}
{\end{itemize}}

\begin{sss}
\item gugus
\end{sss}
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually a key value parser needs to see the syntax characters `=` and `,` directly. Therefore, the macro `\sss` should be expanded once. This can be done with lots of `\expandafter`:

```
\expandafter\begin\expandafter{\expandafter i\expandafter t ...\expandafter}\expandafter[\sss]
```

or the whole expression can be expanded as macro:

```
\edef\next{%
  \noexpand\begin{itemize}[\unexpanded\expandafter{\sss}]%
}\next
```

Here, `\unexpanded` prevents the further expansion of `\sss` after it was expanded once to prevent values from expanding too early.

Comment: Do you have some good reference to learn about *expansions*?

Comment: "The TeXbook" by Donald E. Knuth or ["TeX by Topics"](http://ctan.org/pkg/texbytopic) by Victor Eijkhout.